# Chrome extension how to open new window and send infromation from active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, selenium-ide, browser-extension

I'm trying to do something similar to Selenium IDE (Browser extension).
I would like to:

1 Open new window

2 Record actions from active tab and send it to my new window

But I'm doing something wrong because I'm receiving error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://djnljameancbknhjdldffnejafgfkamf/dialog.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
    at chrome-extension://djnljameancbknhjdldffnejafgfkamf/background.js:35:21
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Dialog tester",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "open-dialog.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "dialog.html",
    "style.css"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
// Handle requests for passwords

var createdWindow;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.type === 'request_password') {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL('dialog.html'),
            active: false
        }, function(tab) {
            // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab
            chrome.windows.create({
                tabId: tab.id,
                type: 'popup',
                focused: true
                // incognito, top, left, ...
            }, function (window) {
                console.log(window);
                // Trace tab id which is created with this query
                createdWindow = window.tabs[0].id
            });
        });
        document.writeln("fsfs");
    }
});
function setPassword(password) {
    // Do something, eg..:
    console.log(password);
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // Inject script into chosen tab after it is loaded completely
    if (tabId == createdWindow && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        // Inject Jquery and in current tab
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            "file": "jquery.js"
        }, function () {
            // I am in call back
            console.log("Injected some jquery ");
        });
    }
});
```

**dialog.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Dialog test</title></head><body>
<form>
    <input id="pass" type="password">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
<script src="dialog.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

**dialog.js**

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent submission
    var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgWindow) {
        bgWindow.setPassword(password);
        window.close();     // Close dialog
    });
};
```

**open-dialog.js**

```
if (confirm('Open dialog for testing?'))
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'request_password'});
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject content script into extension pages which have `chrome-extension://` scheme. Simply reference the scripts in your internal page (dialog.html):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Also, to create a window with `popup` type there's no need to do all that you do. [Create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) it directly:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.type === 'request_password') {
        chrome.windows.create({
            url: '/dialog.html',
            type: 'popup', width: 400, height: 400,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But if I can't inject scripts to chrome-extension:// scheme files so how I can change content of popup depends of user action on active tab? Do you think this is possible?

Comment: You can use conditions and show/hide parts of HTML. Or use chrome.browserAction.setPopup.

Comment: But in this approach I see that I wont be able to log in popup all user actions that he did on active tab? For example I would like to log in popup User click link with name X, User click button with name Y etc

Comment: I don't see how why you won't be able to do that.